# Add GUI with Swing, but unsure of the sequence to take

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics

I'm building a GUI for a data processing algorithm. I can instantiate the window, give it a background, title, etc., but when I try adding panels to it, I run into trouble. What I'm really looking for more than a proofreader is a suggestion for the sequence in which to build, configure, and add objects in Java Swing so that they behave correctly, in a generic sense. So, is this the best way to build a JFrame with a different-colored panel in it?

1. Declare JFrame
2. Set JFrame color (background color)
3. Declare JPanel (box to represent data graphically)
4. Set JPanel color (box color)
5. Add JPanel to JFrame
6. Set JFrame to visible = true

It makes sense intuitively but it doesn't seem to work, no matter what I do. I've found step-by-step instructions elsewhere but they tend to explain what to type more than why you're typing it, so you get a very narrow understanding of what's going on. Thanks for any help!

Below is the full code; I hesitated to post it because I'd begun experimenting with Graphics2D and it isn't well-commented, but if it helps:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;


public class GUI extends JFrame
{
    JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame();
    JPanel backgroundPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();

    Color background = new Color(40,40,40);
    Color subWindow = new Color(255, 255, 255);

    TitledBorder title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("title");

    Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 40, 40);
    Graphics2D g;

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        new GUI();
    }

    public GUI()
    {
        initializeGUI();
    }

    private void initializeGUI() 
    {
        mainWindow.setSize(1340, 880);

        backgroundPanel.setBackground(background);
        subPanel.setBackground(subWindow);
        subPanel.setBorder(title);

        mainWindow.setTitle("Ed");

        mainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        mainWindow.add(backgroundPanel);
        backgroundPanel.add(subPanel);

        updateGUI();

    }

    public void updateGUI()
    {
        mainWindow.setVisible(false);
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        this.g.setColor(subWindow);
        this.g.fill(rect1);
        this.g = (Graphics2D) g;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Logic seems find. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Yep. You're in effect asking why your code isn't working, and to help you with that, you need to post code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this down....

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {
    JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame();
```

There is no need to `extend` from `JFrame` as you are neither using it nor are you adding any value to the class.

This...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    this.g.setColor(subWindow);
    this.g.fill(rect1);
    this.g = (Graphics2D) g;
}
```

is doing nothing and will never be called, as nothing you've extended from implements a `paintComponent` method (that is, `JFrame` does not have a `paintComponent` methd) (and you class is not attached to anything displayed on the screen anyway).  Also, you should NEVER maintain a reference to ANY `Graphics` context you did not create yourself.

The reason that `subPanel` is appearing so "small" is because it has not definable size, aside from the border.

You could rectify this in one of three ways...

1. You could change the layout manager of `backgroundPanel` to something like `BorderLayout`
2. You could override the `getPreferredSize` method of the `subPanel` to return a more suitable size or
3. You could add other components to it and let the layout manager figure it out...

In any case, you should have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

You should also have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting is done in Swing